# backup time machine style

Tags: find, exec, cp, backup

I would like to find a more solid and handy solution to my small problem.. My idea is to backup every midnight my home directory incrementally, so I want only the modified files (of today) to be copied to my external drive. I have prepared a script which does this:

```
find /home/user/* -mtime -1 -exec cp -r {} /media/Elements/BACKUP/ \;
```

It works but I noticed that it does not keep the full path name, and after the first day under /media/Elements/BACKUP I find all the latest files, as example:

If I modify /home/user/a/b/c.dat I'll find c.dat under /media/Elements/BACKUP/c.dat but I would like to have it of course under /media/Elements/BACKUP/a/b/c.dat
Is there an simple flag to add to "find".. or some other trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier to use a program like rsync instead of cp. rsync is designed to do that kind of stuff.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: yes but once, unfortunately, it messed up a lots of things.. I wanted something basic I can control, like cp..

Comment: actually after long time.. I tried again rsync and it works quite well!